# What the meaning of runat="client" (If it exist)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, runatserver, runat

I'm writing an ASPx page in my MVC project with my VisualStudio 2017 with ReSharper installed when, writing a runat server part, ReSharper gave me two options in the runat attribute: server and client.
What is the meaning of runat="client"? Is that an error of ReSharper?

Comment: From what is written here only option is runat="server" https://forums.asp.net/t/955696.aspx?runat+client+vs+runat+server+What+are+the+options+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I don't know anything about ReShaper, but in ASP the option 'runat="server"' is used for have access in the code behind (CS/VB) like for example:

```
*ASP page
<asp:Label id"label" runat="server"></asp:Label>

CS page
label.Text = "Here you can change label text";

VB page
label.Text = "Here you can change label text"
```

The option  'runat="client"' that you are talking doesn't exist in asp.net, i have search for that and it exist in other languanges but not in asp.

Hope it's usefull!

Regards